# mailto: links not opening mail app on UWP ionic app when the body length is more than 2009

Tags: uwp, outlook, ionic3, mailto

I am trying to open email app outlook(office 365) from my ionic UWP app and I am passing the subject & body as variable string and if the length of the body value is more than 2009 email is not opening, any way we can increase this limit?

```
 window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=BenchNotes&body=" + str;
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is browser specific - it is 2083 characters for IE and 2048 for Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "mailto:" protocol doesn't guarantee that Outlook will be opened on the end user machine. A default email client will be run for processing the link with parameters.

You can automate Outlook from your UWP. A supported way to do this is via a full-trust process that you can launch from your UWP. Following that way, your UWP will be able to manipulate the Office apps. Look at [Desktop Bridge samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples).